# Is there a way to refer to the biblical state of Israel in another name?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, proper-nouns

The biblical and modern day states of Israel have the same name, even though they are not the same entities.

Is there a name for the biblical state of Israel which is diffrent from Israel?
Like the name *Israelite* refers to the ancient Jews/people of Israel and not to the citizen of modern day Israel (which are called *Israeli*).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_Israel

Comment: also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_ancient_Israel_and_Judah

Comment: Land of Canaan or Palestine? Promise land

Comment: @Nile and mplungjan, Land of Canaan and Land of Israel describe the geographical area, not the political entity. Palestine, if referred as a territory is the same, if referred to the political entity, then it's unrelated at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to make this distinction is to refer to *the kingdom of Israel*. Since the modern political entity is a republic, that will serve to distinguish them.

Comment: Unless you are talking about a period that distinguishes the kingdom of Israel from the Kingdom of Judah

Comment: @mgb Yes, and furthermore, tradition has it that the ancient Israelites were not always ruled by kings: at other periods the final authorities were judges or tribal elders.

Comment: @MετάEd fair point, but was there a political entity called Israel at the time? I was under the impression that the _country_, not the nation, of Israel had always been a kingdom until it was reestablished in the last century. Is that wrong?

Comment: @terdon In modern parlance, a state (OP's word) is a geopolitical entity. It seems to be a fact that Israel existed as a distinct geopolitical entity before it was united under a single king. This is not based on any expertise of mine, but on the information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_ancient_Israel_and_Judah#Iron_Age_I_.281200.C2.A0BCE_-_1000.C2.A0BCE.29

Comment: In Old Testament times the notion of the *nation state* did not exist - society was tribal. Some historians argue that the entity - nation state - was given birth only in 1648, by the Peace of Westphalia, ending the Thirty-Years War in Europe.

Answer (score 3):

How about *ancient Israel*?  This parallels the way we talk about *ancient Greece* and *ancient Rome*.